# Grouping ComboBox Items in Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I've a `ComboBox` in Windows Forms Application in which the items needs to displayed as shown in the below pic. I need the solid separator only for the first grouping. Other items can just be displayed with no grouping header. Using `ComboBox` it can be achieved as per requirement or do I have to try any 3rd party controls. Any valuable suggestion will be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle drawing items of `ComboBox` yourself by setting its `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed` and handling `DrawItem` event. Then you can draw that separator under the item which you want:

```
private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
    var txt = "";
    if (e.Index > -1)
        txt = comboBox.GetItemText(comboBox.Items[e.Index]);
    e.DrawBackground();
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, txt, comboBox.Font, e.Bounds, e.ForeColor,
        TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Left);
    if (e.Index == 2 && !e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit)) //Index of separator
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Bottom - 1,
            e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom - 1);
}
```

This part of code `e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit)` is to prevent drawing separator in the edit portion of control.

[image]

**Note**

- The answer satisfies the requirement which you asked for in the question. But  some users may want grouping items with group text and not just separator. To  see a `ComboBox` which supports such group texts you can take a look at [A ComboBox Control with Grouping](http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/104) by Brad Smith. ([Alternate link](https://github.com/BradSmith1985/DropDownControls).)